# How to : Debug UIWindows were created prior to initial application activation

Tags: ios, application-lifecycle

My console posted this error today, `[ApplicationLifecycle] UIWindows were created prior to initial application activation. This may result in incorrect visual appearance.`

This has caused Application UI to not behave properly. I have never seen this before and need some insight on where to start debugging.

```
macOS: Catalina 10.15
XCode version: Version 11.1
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that apps main `UIWindow` should be lazily initiated. Try with this:

```swift
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    lazy var window: UIWindow? = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window?.rootViewController = RootViewController() // root view controller
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: Got rid of the warning!! Thank you